# pgAdmin3 shp2pgsql tools: missing, how to obtain

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-3, shp2pgsql

We currently have installations of `postgreSQL` DBs of 9.3 and 9.4. On our clients in the folder C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL[9.3/9.4]\bin I cannot find the `shp2pgsql` tools.  I thought these older versions had the tool bundled with the with the PostgreSQL client software.

1. Where can we obtain these shapefile import/export tools (is it possible these additional "tools" were not installed when the base client software was installed).
2. If its a separate product that must be installed in addition to the base client software would `QGIS` be able to import a shapefile into our `postgreSQL` database lacking that standalone tool? Our `QGIS` version is v2.18.11

Our `pgAdmin3` version is 1.18.1 - yes this old and we are unable to upgrade at this time!

NOTE: We cannot upgrade

Comment: Thank you for your response JGH. In part somewhat, if you go to that link it appears you have to install the full version of postgreSQL. For instance diving into the v9.4 bucket there are two exe files; one for 32 and 64 bit. That to me indicates you have to reinstall the full client version to find out if the tools are actually included -- so not really.

Comment: just use `ogr2ogr` instead?